# white shadow/border on the left and right sides of imageview inside scrollview

Tags: android, scroll, imageview

As the question explains, there is a fuzzy white border or shadow on the left and right sides of my imageview whenever i scroll away from the edges.  This same shadow does not appear on the top or bottom of the screen, ever.  I need these to go away as they stifle the ability to view the image like i want to.  Does anyone have an idea as to what causes this, and how to get rid of it?

in my xml I have a custom class scrollview, with a horizontalscrollview nested inside, and a relativelayout nested inside of that.  everything works fine except this border/shadow.

Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this will help you. Add this in your scrollView ,

```
android:fadingEdge="none"
```

Comment: It did indeed.  Thank you very much!